# Passing multiple values in a url using checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

I know this may be already answered but i am not able to find anything related to this. So here is the thing i am struggling with :-

I have two value which i am passing in a check box :-

```
<input name='class[]' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value='".$x_value['type1'].":".$x_value['type2']."'>
```

On running :-

```
<input name="class[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2681:14175">
```

So what i want is how can i pass these value separated by ":" in a url.

Something like this :-

http://domainname.com/approve.php?type1=2681&type2=14175

Purpose :-

Actually i am getting those value from API response with CURL and generating multiple checkboxes. Each checkbox contains two value separated with ":".

Now i want to run a separate API in different file which will get values from the URL.

Update : Below is the complete code :-

```
     <?php   
                    foreach($apiResponse['response']['data']  as $x =>$x_value) {


 foreach($x_value  as $x => $x_value) {


    echo "<tr>";
    echo  "<td style='width:10px;'><input name='class[]' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value='".$x_value['type1'].":".$x_value['type2']."'></td>";
    echo  "<td style='width:50px;'>".$x_value['type1']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$x_value['type2']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$x_value['approval_status']."</td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='approve.php?type1=".$x_value['type1_value']."&type2_value=".$x_value['type2_value']."'> Approve </a> </td>";
    echo "<td><a href='reject.php?type1_value=".$x_value['type1_value']."&type2_value=".$x_value['type2_value']."'> Reject </a></td>";



    echo "</tr>";



 }
 }
 ?>
```

Update No. 2 :-

API for getting records :-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Pending apps</title>




 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css">


        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../hasoffers/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
} );        </script>


    <!-- Bootstrap 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->

<!-- Optional theme 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


    <![endif]-->


    <style>
    /*.filterable {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.filterable .panel-heading .pull-right {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled] {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
*/
    </style>



  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">


<?php

error_reporting(0);

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

   // Specify API URL
    define('HASOFFERS_API_URL', 'http://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json');

    // Specify method arguments
    $args = array(
        'NetworkId' => 'abc',
        'Target' => 'Offer',
        'Method' => 'findAllPendingAffiliateApprovals',
        'NetworkToken' => 'asdasdasd',

        'filters' => array(
            'approval_status' => 'pending'
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'affiliate_id',
            'offer_id',
            'approval_status',
            'id'
        )

        //'limit' => '100',
    );

    // Initialize cURL
    $curlHandle = curl_init();

    // Configure cURL request
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, HASOFFERS_API_URL . '?' . http_build_query($args));

    // Make sure we can access the response when we execute the call
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Execute the API call
    $jsonEncodedApiResponse = curl_exec($curlHandle);

    // Ensure HTTP call was successful
    if($jsonEncodedApiResponse === false) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            'API call failed with cURL error: ' . curl_error($curlHandle)
        );
    }

    // Clean up the resource now that we're done with cURL
    curl_close($curlHandle);

    // Decode the response from a JSON string to a PHP associative array
    $apiResponse = json_decode($jsonEncodedApiResponse, true);

    // Make sure we got back a well-formed JSON string and that there were no
    // errors when decoding it
    $jsonErrorCode = json_last_error();
    if($jsonErrorCode !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            'API response not well-formed (json error code: ' . $jsonErrorCode . ')'
        );
    }

    // Print out the response details
    if($apiResponse['response']['status'] === 1) {
        // No errors encountered
    //    echo 'API call successful';
    //    echo PHP_EOL;
     //  echo 'Response Data: ' . print_r($apiResponse['response']['data'], true);
     //   echo PHP_EOL;
    }
    else {
        // An error occurred
        echo 'API call failed (' . $apiResponse['response']['errorMessage'] . ')';
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Errors: ' . print_r($apiResponse['response']['errors'], true);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }

    ?>  




</div>


<div class="container">
    <h3>Affiliates Details</h3>
    <p><span>Total Records:-<?php print_r($apiResponse['response']['data']['count']); ?></span></p>
    <hr>



   <script type="application/javascript">


  function toggleChecked(status) {
  $(".checkbox").each( function() {
    $(this).attr("checked",status);
  })
}

   </script>





            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="filters">
                    <th><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked)"></th>
                        <th>Affiliate Id</th>
                       <!-- <th>Affiliate Name</th> -->
                        <th>Offer ID</th>
                       <!-- <th>Offer Name</th> -->
                       <th>Status</th> 
                       <th>Action</th> 
                        <th>Action</th> 

                      <!--  <th>Adv info</th> -->
                      <!--   <th>Aff Info</th> -->
                       <!--  <th>Date</th> -->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>




                     <?php   
                        foreach($apiResponse['response']['data']  as $x =>$x_value) {
   // echo "Affiliate ID" . $x . ", Value=" ;
    //print_r($x_value);

     foreach($x_value  as $x => $x_value) {

    //  $sss = $x_value['affiliate_id'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo  "<td style='width:10px;'><form><input name='v1' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value='".$x_value['offer_id']."|".$x_value['affiliate_id']."'></form></td>";
        echo  "<td style='width:50px;'>".$x_value['affiliate_id']."</td>";
    //  echo "<td>".$x_value['company']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$x_value['offer_id']."</td>";
    //  echo "<td>".$x_value['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$x_value['approval_status']."</td>";
        echo "<td> <a href='approve.php?offerid=".$x_value['offer_id']."&affid=".$x_value['affiliate_id']."'> Approve </a> </td>";
        echo "<td><a href='reject.php?offerid=".$x_value['offer_id']."&affid=".$x_value['affiliate_id']."'> Reject </a></td>";

    //  echo "<td>".$x_value['advertiser_info']."</td>";
    //  echo "<td>".$x_value['affiliate_info1']."</td>";
    //  echo "<td>".$x_value['datetime']."</td>";

        echo "</tr>";



     }


}
?>





                </tbody>
            </table>

</div>



<?php

list($value1,$value2) = explode('|', $_GET['v1']);
echo "value1 = ".$value1.", value2 = ".$value2."<br>";

?>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed 
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

API to change status of the multiple records :-

Second URL will become like this :-

http://www.domain.com/approve.php?offerid=123&affid=456

Out of which offer id and affid will be passed from checkbox value

```
<?php
// Specify API URL
define('HASOFFERS_API_URL', 'http://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json');

// Specify method arguments
$args = array(
    'NetworkId' => 'anc',
    'Target' => 'Offer',
    'Method' => 'setAffiliateApproval',
    'NetworkToken' => 'asdasdasdasd',
    'id' => '' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["offerid"]) .'',
    'affiliate_id' => '' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["affid"]) .'',
    'status' => 'approved'
);

// Initialize cURL
$curlHandle = curl_init();

// Configure cURL request
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, HASOFFERS_API_URL);

// Configure POST
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($args));

// Make sure we can access the response when we execute the call
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute the API call
$jsonEncodedApiResponse = curl_exec($curlHandle);

// Ensure HTTP call was successful
if($jsonEncodedApiResponse === false) {
    throw new \RuntimeException(
        'API call failed with cURL error: ' . curl_error($curlHandle)
    );
}

// Clean up the resource now that we're done with cURL
curl_close($curlHandle);

// Decode the response from a JSON string to a PHP associative array
$apiResponse = json_decode($jsonEncodedApiResponse, true);

// Make sure we got back a well-formed JSON string and that there were no
// errors when decoding it
$jsonErrorCode = json_last_error();
if($jsonErrorCode !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    throw new \RuntimeException(
        'API response not well-formed (json error code: ' . $jsonErrorCode . ')'
    );
}

// Print out the response details
if($apiResponse['response']['status'] === 1) {
    // No errors encountered
    echo 'API call successful';
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Response Data: ' . print_r($apiResponse['response']['data'], true);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
else {
    // An error occurred
    echo 'API call failed (' . $apiResponse['response']['errorMessage'] . ')';
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Errors: ' . print_r($apiResponse['response']['errors'], true);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

?>



<script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
        function Redirect() {
           window.location="index.php";
        }

        document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 2 sec.");
        setTimeout('Redirect()', 2000);
     //-->
  </script>
```

Code added :-

[image]

Main objective is that i want to change status of those records with another API, and to do that i need two value from a single checkbox

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely

Comment: For passing in url you need to use `GET` method, you can do something like this : `$x_value['type1'].".".$x_value['type2'];`

Comment: Where you need to run your api ? Can't you explode before passing to api ?

Comment: @Rishi : That is the issue here, i am not sure how to do that. I am actually new to php.

Answer (score 0):

page1.php:

```
<input name="v1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2681|14175">
```

page2.php:

```
<?php

list($value1,$value2) = explode('|', $_GET['v1']);
echo "value1 = ".$value1.", value2 = ".$value2."<br>";

?>
```

let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: This i am able to do. The main issue is i need to get two value from 1 checkbox and needed to pass in url. Please see i have updated the question with more details.

Comment: @VineetSharma I modified my answer, let me know if that works well for you!

Comment: I have tried that, but its not displaying results. Seems like its not getting values from check box.

Comment: @Vineet Sharma it works for me... edit your answer with all of your code, including form tags, etc, so that I can understand whats happening.

Comment: :- I have updated the question with complete code. Please have a look.

Comment: From what I see, you have not changed this part of the code:  `echo  "<td style='width:10px;'><input name='class[]' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value='".$x_value['type1'].":".$x_value['type2']."'></td>";` to  `echo  "<td style='width:10px;'><input name='v1' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value='".$x_value['type1']."|".$x_value['type2']."'></td>";` Now as I see your code is a lot longer than I thought, you might want to use the 'name' you already had so that other parts of your code don't break.

Comment: Webeng :- i have added the code like you mentioned. Please check the code updated at end. Also, i am not using checkbox name anywhere else.

Comment: I just checked, you have not added it. In the previous thing I pasted in the comments, the difference was: class[] -> v1, and ":" -> "|". If you don't try out what I'm saying then I can't help you...

Comment: Hi Webeng, i apologise. But i dunno why its not visible to you. I had made the same changes like you mentioned. I have attached the screenshot where i had mentioned in code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to get URL like this

http://domainname.com/approve.php?type1=2681&type2=14175

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $urldata=explode(":",$_POST['class'][0]);
 }

 ?>
<form method="post" action='<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {?  >index.php? type1=<?php echo $urldata[0]."&type2=".$urldata[1] ?> <?php } ?>'>

<input name='class[]' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value='55:1444'>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: ram singh - I need 2 two button for different purpose. I have updated the question. Please have a look.